# C string input overflows other string input

Tags: c, arrays, string

I'm doing a simple console type command system, and inputting a command will scanf an integer and then will scanf a string, but the contents of the second string overflows the original string

```
while (exit == 0) {
    scanf("%s", input);

    if (strcmp(input, "parent") == 0) {
        free(input);
        ptemp = malloc(sizeof(node_p));

        printf("Id: ");
        scanf("%d", &ptemp->itemid);
        printf("\nElement:");
        scanf("%s", ptemp->element);

        add_parent_node(parent, ptemp->itemid, ptemp->element);

        free(ptemp);
    }
}
```

`ptemp` is a pointer to a struct containing:

```
int itemid;
char *element;
```

I've tried using arrays with predefined size, but nothing seems to work...

Comment: You didn't overflow anything.  You wrote data to an uninitialized pointer.  This is undefined behaviour.  Also, what type is `ptemp`? Show us the definition of `node_p` -- it looks like it might be a typedef to a pointer type, which would mean you have other problems too.

Comment: Note that using a variable called `exit` while you've got `<stdlib.h>` included (for `free()` and `malloc()`) means you're hiding the [`exit()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exit.html) function — you couldn't call `exit(EXIT_FAILURE);` from within your function.  This isn't formally an error, but it is not good practice and it is better not to learn bad habits.

Comment: `scanf("%s")` is unsafe because you don't set an upper-bound on the length of the string, which can cause buffer-overflows. Use `scanf("%99s")` for a `char[100]` buffer, for example (+1 for the trailing null).

Comment: 1- Exit is just an int variable, this is not the full code, only part of it.

Comment: 2- typedef struct parent {
 int itemid;
 struct parent * next;
 struct child * children;
 char *element;
} node_p;

Comment: 3- Overflow im atlking about is that whenever all the code in the if is done exacuting and goes back to the top, everything i input to input will not work and inputing parent a second time makes the program crash.

Comment: What is `input` ? How is it declared, how is it initialized ? What is `ptemp` ? You forgot to show essential parts of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Someone that made a comment about nothing overflowing is correct. What you were missing were (in laymans terms) a reservation for characters. Declaring something as `char*` instead of `char[xx]` means that you're prepared to reference another part of memory that you're allowed to manipulate with your characters. To keep things simple, I rewritten your code so your program works. Keep in mind that this code relies on users entering strings that are less than 100 to 200 characters long. Feel free to increase the number in square brackets if you need more characters.

I also made an add_parent_node function to verify that the data processing works.

If you want to get a little paranoid and you feel your systems implementation of scanf is screwy, then you can place the following under the while statement:

```
memset(ptemp,0,sizeof(ptemp));
```

What that does is floods the entire struct with null characters. This means the value of itemid would be zero since zero is null, and element would be 200 null characters.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct{
  int itemid;
  char element[200]; //fixed array of chars to actually store a string
}mycollection;

void add_parent_node(char* parentnodename,int itemid,char* element){
  printf("Added node as follows\n");
  printf("Parent: %s\n",parentnodename);
  printf("Item ID: %d\n",itemid);
  printf("Element: %s\n\n",element);
}

int main(){
  char input[100]; //limit command to 99 characters
  mycollection ptemp[1];
  while(1){ //while(1) = endless loop
      printf("\nEnter command: ");
      scanf("%s", input);
      if (strcmp(input, "parent") == 0) {
      printf("\nId: ");
      scanf("%d", &ptemp->itemid);
      printf("\nElement:");
      scanf("%s", ptemp->element);
      add_parent_node("im_the_parent", ptemp->itemid, ptemp->element);
      }
      if (strcmp(input, "exit") == 0) {
      return 0; //return 0 = exit
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sadly trying to use any parts of this breaks my program and makes it uable to compile...

Comment: I wrote this in linux and it uses standard libraries. Do you have the standard libraries installed on your computer in the standard location? and did you try compiling with warnings enabled?

Comment: My program ins't only what i wrote in the original post, it is only part of one function in a bigger program.

Comment: You're better off posting more of your program so we can figure out what really doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change anything outside your while loop I think this is what you can do.

```
while (exit == 0) {
    scanf("%s", input);

    if (strcmp(input, "parent") == 0) {
        if(0 == ptemp ){
            /* Allocate memory only once and reuse it.*/
            ptemp = malloc(sizeof(node_p));
            /* Allocate memory for element. */
            ptemp->element = malloc(sizeof(char) * 1024 /* Max string len + 1 */)
        }

        printf("Id: ");
        scanf("%d", &ptemp->itemid);
        printf("\nElement:");
        scanf("%s", ptemp->element);

        add_parent_node(parent, ptemp->itemid, ptemp->element);
    }

    else if (strcmp(input, "exit") == 0) {
       if(0 != ptemp){
           /* If memory is allocated for ptemp, free it. */
           if(0 != ptemp->element){
               free(ptemp->element);
               ptemp->element = 0;
           }

           free(ptemp);
           ptemp = 0;
       }
       free(input);
       input = 0;

       exit = 1;
       break;
    }
}
```